# Bulk upload/import to Firebase with auto generated keys

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to upload bulk rows of data using Firebase console's 'Import JSON' utility. But I could not get a way to enable Auto Generated Keys like -Kop90...  for each rows. But instead it created 0,1.. keys.

This is my sample data

```
[
{"date":1448323200,"description":"test data1","amount":1273},
{"date":1448323200,"description":"25mm pipes","amount":2662}
]
```

I would like to generate something like this

[image: data with auto generated keys]

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. But if you want to generate push IDs (the keys currently starting with `-K`) yourself in your code, have a look at this [blog post explaining Firebase's push IDs](firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

Comment: My data is in excel and is having hundreds of rows. I created a vba code to generate JSON in a format that mentioned in the question. This JSON was saved in a text file and was trying to upload to my firebase account using 'Import JSON' utility. But instead of -Kcj-... it was generated 0, 1,2 etc. I Know how to use java script to upload each row one by one to enable auto generated key like -Kc.., but that does not look efficient.

Comment: That's why I linked you to a post that has the code of how Firebase generates its push IDs. You can just generate the IDs client-side (that's what the Firebase SDKs do) and then post all data as a single block with those pre-generated push IDs.

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: I was not able open your link after copy paste. Anyway I opened the link after google search. Which mean you trying to say that there is no way to enable the firebase import utility to create AUTO gen ID for me,? I have to create my self and add to each row.?

Comment: I'm not sure why that link doesn't work, but here's an updated one: [https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html). To have the Firebase REST API generate an ID, you can send a POST request to it. But that'd mean you have to POST each row separately. If you want to send the JSON in one HTTP request, you have to generate the IDs client-side before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours,

I ended up finding a nice solution for the firestore using JS & Node: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qg2_VFFcAI8&ab_channel=RetroPortalStudio

But since I needed it for the Realtime Database I just altered it slightly to suit my needs:

**Pre-requisites:**

1. JS SDK installation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0#add-sdk-and-initialize
2. Using SDK version 8 (namespaced) [Could be easily altered for use in v9]

**Steps:**

1. Create folder called **files** in root project directory:
2. Add all your json files as shown below:

[image]

3. Add the following code to a file (in this example the file is called **"uploader.js"**):

NOTE: The only thing missing from the below code is the firebaseConfig obj, you can get this obj by following this guide: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

```js
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/database");

const firebaseConfig = {
  // your config details...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = firebase.database();

// File directory details:
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "files");

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
  }

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var lastDotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");

    var items = require("./files/" + file);

    var listRef = database.ref(`${file.substring(0, lastDotIndex)}/`);

    items.forEach(function(obj) {
      var postRef = listRef.push();
      
      postRef.set(obj)
      .then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document written");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });

    });
  });
});
```

4. Lastly, open the terminal to the directory where **uploader.js** can be found & run:

```js
node uploader.js
```

After the running the operation, each file becomes a collection, and all the contents of each file are listed with a unique pushId:

[image]