# Firebase DB, What is the ID Name for Client Built Push IDs

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

In regards to the answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181328/bulk-upload-import-to-firebase-with-auto-generated-keys/47530044), what would be the name of the push ID? I've tried `.ref('/parent/{pushId}')` & `.child(key)` all with no luck.

Comment: You generate a push key like var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('parent').push().key and then use it to submit any data to the db like updates['/parent/' + newPostKey] = postData; You can then get it as an index when you get the parent object.

Comment: @isz thanks for the reply. What if I'm doing a bulk upload to the db via a JSON file that already includes IDs I've generated? (i.e. IDs not generated via `.push().key`). How would I go about querying these specific IDs similar to calling `{uid}`?

Comment: There really isn't anything special about the Push Ids, you can generate your own and as long as they are unique they will perform the same. You also access them the same way as any other node var parentRef = firebase.database().ref('parents/'+pushKey) parentRef.on('value', function(snapshot){console.log(snapshot.val())}) Just avoid using ids in your json that might not stay unique i.e. 0 1 2